# How can I optimize an alert system that processes 10k requests / job?

Tags: python, node.js, architecture, software-design

I'm build a solution `Match Service` where receive data from a third party provider from MQTT server. This data is a realtime data. We save this data in RDS Cluster.

Our users can create in another service a filter called `Strateg`, we send a cron every 5 minutes to this service and all records in database are send to Kafka topic to be processed in `Match Service`.

My design is based on events, so each new `Strategy` record in topic, `Match Service` performs a query in database for check if have any `Match` that active the `Strategy` threshold. If the threshold is passed, it sends out an new message to broker.

The API processes about 10k `Strategy` in each job, it's taking timing (about 250s for each job).

So my question is if there is a better way to design this system? I was thinking of adding a redis-layer, to avoid database transactions.

[image: Atual arch]

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Think long and hard about your relational data store.  If you really need it to be relational, then it may absolutely make sense, but if not, a relational database is often a horrible place to dump things like time-series and IoT output.  It's a great place to put normalized, structured data for reporting, but a lousy dump/load location and real-time matching.

Look more at something like AWS RedShift, ElasticSearch, or some other no-sql solution that can ingest and match things at orders of magnitude higher scale.

Comment: My data in Match Service is relational and the queries created by user in `Strategy Service` is to filter `Match` models and the relations. It's like `Match` have N `Stats`, so, user want to be notify when a `Stat` with `Stat.key` equals to "ABC" and `Stat.value` greater than 5.